# Why is there a time discrepancy between VOY: Flashback and The Undiscovered Country?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In [VOY: Flashback](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flashback_(episode)), the Praxis explosion happens and then they say a few days later they learned that two Starfleet officers had been arrested for the assassination of Chancellor Gorkon, etc. and they attempt to launch a rescue attempt.

However, in the film [The Undiscovered Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country), Spock says that the explosion happened *several months ago*.

**Is there any canon explanation for the discrepancy e.g. dream vs memory?**

Comment: Welcome and congratulations on your first post! I'm not really sure what you are asking here. Maybe edit your post to include a specific question for us to answer.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Although it's not phrased as a question, the intent is clear, and the references are well-known to *Star Trek* fans: the OP is seeking an explanation for an apparent timing discrepancy between *Star Trek VI* and the *Voyager* episode "Flashback". For readers unfamiliar with the movie and the episode, a bit of background information in the question would be helpful, but we can request that without immediately putting the question on hold.

Comment: @Gaultheria in which case I strongly suggest you edit it to clarify for us unfamiliar folks ;) from where I stand, I don't vote to reopen a question when I don't see the beginning of one, or y'know, the ending of one... An actual question with a question mark and everything would be an improvement, so that everyone can clearly see what's asked and not rely on "it's so obvious for fans" claims ;)

Comment: @Jenayah - I'm primarily concerned with how the site-wide "be nice" policy seems to be getting short shrift regarding this first-time poster.

Comment: @Gaultheria don't hesitate to tell me if you think I'm not nice, but regardless of the poster, we're supposed to vote for the _content_, and right now, the content is unclear. I myself can't make it a better question because I don't understand it. But it seems _you_ can, and community edits are a big part of SE's philosophy, so rather than debating whether a stock close reason is nice or not, I think we'd be more welcoming by turning that question into a better fit, then voting to reopen. Teach a man to fish and all that, no? :)

Comment: @Jenayah - All I'm saying is that we can be gentler (especially to newcomers) when requesting clarification. Getting the big, colourful **"Put on hold"** banner right away comes across as a reprimand rather than a friendly request.

Comment: For the record, a canon is a body of works by the same author, a cannon is a gigantic metal thing that goes "Boom!"

Comment: Thanks for your comments and especially to Valorum for the re-edit of the question!

Comment: @Gaultheria Ironically the "on hold" function was created to be more friendly. Before, they simply got closed.

Comment: @Gaultheria That banner serves a vital purpose. We do have strict controls here. The question can be re-opened when it is a question (which is what has since happened). This has nothing to do with "being nice" or otherwise

Answer (score 5):

It is abundantly clear in this episode that Tuvok's memories that the *Voyager* characters are exploring are not entirely accurate, at best.  The whole attempt by Janeway and Tuvok himself to explore Tuvok's memory goes wrong from the very outset, when the pair do not end up in the memory they were aiming for.  Subsequently, things go further "off the rails," to the point where what Tuvok and Janeway are experiencing is manifestly not a memory at all, but rather a new fantasy version of past events, which Tuvok's mind is inventing in response to Tuvok and Janeway's actions during the meld.

So the simplest explanation is that the dating issue is just an error in the way Tuvok is recalling the incidents.  He is not in great mental shape as he and his captain go traipsing through his recollections.  The critical events (the explosion as witnessed by the Excelsior, then the incidents with Kirk and McCoy) have been compressed together into a more compact narrative by Tuvok's faulty mind.

Comment: I never noticed the time discrepancy before.  However the Dmitri Valtane death many noticed at the time.  I tell people he was just badly burned and Tuvoks memories are obviously damaged.